# Limit of a sequence involving $\cos\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and the $n$-th root

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm having some troubles figuring out how to solve the sequent limit:
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{1-\cos{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}}
$$

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sqrt[n]{1-\cos{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}} & = \sqrt[n]{2\sin^2{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}}\\
&=2^{1/n}\left[\sin^{2}{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}\right]^{1/n}\\
&=2^{1/n}\left[\sin^{2}{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}\frac{1/4n^2}{1/4n^2}\right]^{1/n}\\
&=\left[\frac{\sin^{2}{\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)}}{1/(2n)^2}\right]^{1/n}\left[\frac{1}{2n^2}\right]^{1/n}.
\end{align*}
Now use the following standard limits:
$$\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin \theta }{\theta}=1, \lim_{n \to \infty}n^{1/n}=1, \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{1/n}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

$$\cos\frac1n=1-\frac1{2n^2}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\implies 1-\cos\frac1n=\frac1{2n^2}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\implies$$

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac1{2n^2}}\le\sqrt[n]{1-\cos\frac1n}\le1$$

Answer (score 0):

We can write

$$\sqrt[n]{1-\cos(1/n)} =2^{1/n}\sin^{2/n}(2/n)$$

Exploiting the elementary inequalities

$$2x/\pi \le \sin(x)\le x$$

for $0\le x\le \pi/2$, we find that

$$2^{1/n}(2/\pi)^{2/n} (2/n)^{2/n}\le \sqrt[n]{1-\cos(1/n)} \le 2^{1/n} (2/n)^{2/n}$$

whereupon applying the squeeze theorem yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{1-\cos(1/n)}=1$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit of course.